# Pointer to address and Memory Stack

Tags: c++, memory-management

```
void EventsStack::push(Event *e){
    EventNode *q = new EventNode();
    q->data = e;
    q->next = _top;
    _top = q;
}

void main() {
    EventsStack eventStack;
    Event e1(1);
    eventStack.push(&e1);
    Event e2(2);
    eventStack.push(&e2);
}
```

First question: when I do

```
eventStack.push(&e1);
```

am I sending the ADDRESS of e1 to the push function, and the push function receiving it as a pointer? as if I am doing:

```
Event *e = 1000 (1000 is the offset (address) of e1 for example on the stack)
```

?

Second question: I am asked to illustrate the stack upon running the main function. When I get to the line

```
eventStack.push(&e1);
```

does a 4 byte return address and a 4byte pointer to e1 get allocated as the function's activation frame or in this situation there is no activation frame since eventStack is an object of the class EventsStack and the push is one of its' member functions?

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org/Stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question, yes: the `&` operator yields the memory address of your Event.

As to your second question, well, it's complicated. The description you made seems to indicate an underlying confusion as to how the stack works. I'd strongly recommend going over some introductory material on the topic, it's going to leave you with a much stronger understanding.

You'll be able to answer your own question a few hours from now if you go Google a bit :).

Comment: actually, the answer to the first question may not be yes.  *1000 is the offset (address) of e1 for example on the stack*.... does that sound right to you?

Comment: According to what my professors say... yes.
Event e1(1). Creates e1 on the stack, whom's start address is 1000. I send &e1 to the function which is its' address: 1000. The function gets it as Event* e. Thus: Event *e = 1000 or.... am I wrong?

Comment: @TheNotMe It's reasonable to speak of `e1` being created on the stack, even if there is no hardware stack, because the lifetimes of local variables behave as if they were on a stack (which must be emulated somehow if there is no direct hardware support).  And the address 1000 sounds like they're explaining things in terms of an abstract machine, rather than any concrete hardware.  So you'll have to look in the specifications of this abstract machine for the exact answer, since we don't have access to those specifications.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your first question: the expression `&e1` takes
the address of `e1`, which is a pointer.  In other words, `e1`
has type `Event`, and `&e1` has type `Event*`, and a value such
that dereferencing it (the unary `*` operator) will have the
same effect as using `e1`.  This is what you pass to the push
function.

And a pointer cannot be just an offset on the stack, since it
must be possible to access the object with it from elsewhere,
where the stack isn't necessarily available.  Most modern
desktop machines use linear addressing, which means that the
pointer is simply an integer, but that hasn't always been the
case, and it's probably not the case on some embedded processors
(and for historical reasons on some mainframes).

With regards to the second question: formally, it's completely
unspecified *how* functions are called.  What is necessary is
that the compiler put the return address and the arguments
somewhere where the called function can find them.  In the
expression `eventStack.push( &e1 )`, the function has two
arguments, the address of `eventStack` (which will become the
`this` pointer in the function), and the expression `&e1`.  How
the compiler passes these in varies enormously, and almost
always depends on their type, but *usually*, on most modern
machines, the first 3 to 5 arguments will go into machine
registers if they fit (and both of the addresses you pass will
fit), so all that gets pushed on the machine stack is the return
address.  And parameters are not usually considered part of the
current frame, although on some older processors, the compiler
did treat them as such.  (You say you are "asked to illustrate
the stack".  Does the question refer to a specific machine
architecture, or what?  What actually happens on the stack will
vary enormously between compilers, and g++ under Linux will
often do something completely different than Visual Studios,
even when running on the same processor.)

Comment: it makes matters worse when the class is called eventstack... does stack refer to that object?  or does it refer to the machine's calling stack.

Comment: @thang That's another possibility.  The mention of an address, with a numeric value, makes me think that he means the stack used by the generated code to support recursive calls, but you never know.  Anyhow, I think the key points are 1) `EventStack::push` takes two arguments, not one, and 2) how arguments are passed is very implementation dependent, and pushing them on the machine stack is usually only used when no other alternatives are available.  It's probably worth mentionning too that on modern machines, addresses are usually 8 bytes, not 4 (but of course, they can be any size).